# Make each Value of custom field show related posts when clicked

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

i have create a Custom Post Type calle "Places". I have created a Custom Field with

Field Type "Multi CheckBox" Option Title "Type of Pub" Option values "Sports, Rock, Biker, Beer, Live Band, Restro, Gastro, Irish, Karaoke Bar" Field Title "Type of Pub" Field name "typeofpub"

Basically turn option value to tags, so that once someone clicks on sports, it will show the archive page of sports showing all the posts with option value sports.

Comment: you can save each option of 'typeofpub' like tag in taxonomy "post_tag", using [`wp_set_object_terms();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) function in your save_post hook of your metabox. At this point why don't use post tags instead of custom fields? i guess,  because you don't want to let the users can set "invalid" tag terms, it is right?

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit more on how can i do this. you can see it on this page http://cludoc.com/insane/places/extreme-sports-bar/ that type of pub: sports, rock they are just text now. i want to turn them to clickable links and when clicked to show all the posts with the same type of pub: sports or rock

Comment: Are you using custom metabox with typeofpub custom field?

Comment: no, i dont think so.

Comment: ok, i think you don't need custom fields for this task. Please use post tag, instead. You can register a custom taxonomy ( typeofpub ) with [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for your custom post type.

Comment: i am using a custom post type Creator, which itself allows me to create custom fields associated with custom post types. thats why i am asking how can i convert custom fields values to tags

Comment: I see it just now ( [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/screenshots/) ), you can set also custom taxonomies.

Comment: no i am not using that plugin, i am using a plugin called tevolution by templatic.com which is similar to other plugins